# I am not able to configure ehcache with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

corresponding jar files i used are below :

- ehcache-3.2.0
- hibernate-ehcache-5.0.2.Final
- hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final

configuration is like this :

```
  <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop> 
 <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" >true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
 <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

I am getting error like this :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException

help me to getout of this issue.

Comment: Looks like ehcache libraries are not added to classpath

Comment: Show your java code first where you are doing transaction to the database.

Comment: public <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Long id) throws Exception {
        return (T) entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need this artifact:

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId> 
   <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId> 
   <version>2.10.3</version> 
</dependency>
```

It contains the `net.sf.ehcache` packages / classes that your application is looking for.

Based on your hibernate property:

```
<prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

Comment: thanks @kowalski now i am not getting any issue.But how to test this.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. What is it you want to test exactly?

Comment: i added configurations to save entities and hql queries into ehcache.Now i want to know whether these are really saved or not.

Comment: don't mix ehcache2 and ehcache3; choose only 1 and stick with it; the question explicitly mentioned ehcache3

Answer (score 6):

You are using Ehcache 3 (which is good) but are using a region factory that is Ehcache 2 compatible.

For Ehcache 3, which is JCache compliant, you should use `org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory`.

You will find a full example here: https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/tree/master/fullstack. Have a look at the `README.md` to find the interesting files.

**Note:** As Louis mentioned in the comment, you need Hibernate 5.2 to get JCache support.

Comment: Note that this requires Hibernate 5.2+